# Möbius inversion for locally finite poset

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

I'm trying to understand this paper: Rota, Gian-Carlo. "On the foundations of combinatorial theory I. Theory of Möbius functions." Or at least, to understand the first few pages.

In particular, I'm having some trouble understanding the claim that the möbius inversion formula does in fact provide the inverse of the zeta function. [That is, inverse in the incidence algebra where composition is by convolution and the identity is the Kronecker delta].

So we have a locally finite partially ordered set, and we define $\zeta(x,y) = 1$ if and only if $x\le y$. 
Also define $\delta(x,y) = 1$ iff $x=y$.
We want to find the $\mu$ such that

$$
\sum_{x\le z\le y} \zeta(x,z)\mu(z,y) = \delta(x,y) 
$$

Rota claims that the $\mu$ that does the trick is defined inductively as follows:
$\mu(x,x) =1$ for all $x$, and if $\mu$ has been defined for all $z$ such that $x\le z <y$, then

$$
\mu(x,y) = -\sum_{x\le z<y} \mu(x,z)
$$

This is well defined since the poset is locally finite.

Rota says "Clearly $\mu$ is an inverse of $\zeta$" but I'm struggling to see how this is at all clear. Could someone give me a hint as to how the proof of this claim would go?

Comment: Inverse is what sense? Their compositions doesn't even make sense.

Comment: The inverse in the incidence algebra.

Comment: @GitGud In the sense described in the square brackets in the second paragraph.

Comment: In fact, I'm not bothered that it's an "inverse" in any sense, I just want to understand how the $\mu$ so defined is related to the $\zeta$ and $\delta$ so defined.

Comment: It's probably more obvious to show that $\mu$ is a LEFT inverse for $\zeta$ (i.e., make the sum $\mu(x, z)\zeta(x, y)$), and use the fact that a right inverse exists and that convolution is associative to prove that $\mu$ is also a right inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a function $f$ in your incidence algebra, you want the inverse, i.e. a function $f^{-1}$ such that $f(x,x)f^{-1}(x,x)=d(x,x)=1$, it means $f^{-1}(x,x)=\frac{1}{f(x,x)}$. And $$\sum _{x\leq z\leq y}f(x,z)f^{-1}(z,y)=\sum _{x<z\leq y}f(x,z)f^{-1}(z,y)+f(x,x)f^{-1}(x,y)=d(x,y)=0,$$ so, by rearranging the terms, $$f^{-1}(x,y)=\frac{1}{f(x,x)}(-\sum _{x<z\leq y}f(x,z)f^{-1}(z,y)).$$ Use $\zeta$ instead of $f$.

**Edit:**
As the OP and Nishant noticed, the restriction in the sum on the Möbius recursion is $x\leq z < y$, for that is to do the same thing done below but using $f^{-1}$ on the left of the convolution, i.e. $$\sum _{x\leq z \leq y}f^{-1}(x,z)f(z,y)=\sum _{x\leq z < y}f^{-1}(x,z)f(z,y)+f^{-1}(x,y)f(y,y).$$It can be done by the fact that Dirichlet convolution is associative.

Comment: This seems to fundamentally misunderstand the question. I don't want a function such that $f(x,x)f^{-1}(x,x) = d(x,x)$, I want a function such that $\sum_{x\le z \le y} f(x,z)f^{-1}(z,y) = d(x,y)$. On a partially ordered set, what does $\frac{1}{f(x,x)}$ even *mean*?

Comment: $d(x,y)$ has two different values, does not it? when $x=y$, that is the first part and when $x\neq y$ that is the second part. So you must see the two parts in order to construct $\mu$.
BtW, in the incidence algebra you need a field (recall the incidence algebra of a poset $\mathbb{A}(P)=\{f:P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{K}:x\not \leq y \Rightarrow f(x,y)=0\}$), $\frac{1}{f(x,x)}$ is the inverse of $f(x,x)$ in the field $\mathbb{K}$..Note that it is well defined because $\zeta$ is not $0$ when $x=y$

Comment: I just saw Rota's paper, there $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$. When rota says "Clearly $\mu$ is the inverse of $\zeta$", he means that he just construct it in the way i wrote in the answer.
Hope it helps

Comment: Oh I think I see. Sorry, I was tired when I read this last night. Perhaps you could expand on the "so" in your answer. i.e. just say that you rearrange the equation above to get an expression for $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Looking at this more carefully, this isn't quite what I need. Note that the summation in your version is over $x < z \le y$ while in the version Rota appeals to, it is $x\le z < y$. I guess this is what Nishant meant be his/her comment on the question. Could you perhaps expand on that step?

Comment: The "So" part is just, as you wrote, rearrange the terms. For getting it you must change the order of the sum. You can do it that because in the incidence algebra you can prove associativity, as Nishant said, i.e. if we denote the convolution by $\star$, $(f\star f^{-1}) \star f =f=f\star (f^{-1} \star  f)$. So, instead of doing $$\sum_{x\leq z\leq y} f(x,z)f^{-1}(z,y),$$you can do it as $$\sum_{x\leq z\leq y} f^{-1}(x,z)f(z,y)=\sum_{x\leq z<y} f^{-1}(x,z)f(z,y)+f^{-1}(x,y)f(y,y).$$ In that way you will have what you want.

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion was that you add this explanation to your answer.

Comment: 0k, i have done it. Glad to help.